# Switching between XML pages on button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created my first android application I have 4 pages, I have set one page to be the menu and it has 3 buttons on it to switch between the pages. However I seem to be getting an error in my code, if someone could take a look and see where I am going wrong with this.

So this is my menu page (**activity_main**)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.ifmdb.MainActivity"
 tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame,HardcodedText" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/please_click_on_the_options_available"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnDOCare"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDOCare"
     android:layout_below="@+id/txtDOCare"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:onClick="openDOCare"
     android:text="@string/duty_of_care" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtDOCare"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/btnDock"
      android:layout_marginLeft="202dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/click_for_duty_of_care"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtVeCheck"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtDOCare"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
       android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
       android:text="@string/click_for_vehicle_checklist"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnDOCare"
       android:layout_below="@+id/txtVeCheck"
       android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
       android:onClick="openChecklist"
       android:text="@string/checklist" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDOCare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/click_for_docket"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDock"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:onClick="openDocket"
        android:text="@string/docket" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my Java class for it (**Main Activity**)

```
  package com.example.ifmdb;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
      btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
     }
           });    
           }

          }
```

This is my second page (**checklist**)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ifmdb.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/vehicle_safety_checklist"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/please_check_each_box"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.58" >

       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtInt"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:text="@string/interior"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtEx"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtInt"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtInt"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
           android:text="@string/exterior"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

         <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/cboxFLev"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/txtInt"
           android:text="@string/fuel_level" />

          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cboxTires"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxFLev"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxFLev"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtEx"
            android:text="@string/tires_wheels" />

          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cboxWWash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cboxFLev"
            android:text="@string/windscreen_washer" />

          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cboxExhaust"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxWWash"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxWWash"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cboxTires"
            android:text="@string/exhaust" />

         <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/cboxSWheel"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/cboxWWash"
           android:text="@string/steering_wheel" />

          <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/cboxLights"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxSWheel"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxSWheel"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cboxExhaust"
           android:text="@string/lights_reflectors" />

           <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/cboxBrakes"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/cboxSWheel"
             android:text="@string/brakes" />

           <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/cboxELeaks"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxBrakes"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxBrakes"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@string/_id_cboxlights"
             android:text="@string/exterior_leaks" />

           <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/cboxClutch"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/cboxBrakes"
             android:text="@string/clutch" />

            <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/cbocBody"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxClutch"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxClutch"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@string/_id_cboxeleaks"
              android:text="@string/body" />

            <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/cboxHorn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/cboxClutch"
              android:text="@string/horn" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtEng"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cbocBody"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cboxHorn"
                android:text="@string/engine"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

              <CheckBox
                 android:id="@+id/cboxHeater"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtEng"
                 android:text="@string/heater" />

               <CheckBox
                  android:id="@+id/cboxOil"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cboxExhaust"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/cboxHeater"
                  android:text="@string/oil_level" />

                <CheckBox
                  android:id="@+id/cboxSBelt"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxOil"
                  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxOil"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:text="@string/seat_belts" />

                 <CheckBox
                   android:id="@+id/cboxWLight"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxCool"
                   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxCool"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:text="@string/warning_lights" />

             <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cboxBelt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cboxCool"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cboxCool"
                android:text="@string/belts" />

            <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/cboxMirrors"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/cboxWLight"
              android:text="@string/mirrors" />

          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/cboxLeaks"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cboxBelt"
              android:layout_below="@+id/cboxBelt"
              android:text="@string/engine_leaks" />

             <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cboxCool"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cboxOil"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cboxOil"
                android:text="@string/coolant_level" />

             <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtOther"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxLeaks"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:text="@string/other"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

              <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cboxScrew"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtEng"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cboxLeaks"
                android:text="@string/loose_bolts_screws" />

               <CheckBox
                 android:id="@+id/cboxWTri"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cboxScrew"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cboxScrew"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:text="@string/warning_triangle" />

          <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/cboxFire"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/cboxWTri"
             android:text="@string/fire_extinguisher_first_aid_kit" />

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddCom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/additional_comments"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

           <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtAddComBox"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cboxLights"
             android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddCom"
             android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFault"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
         android:text="@string/in_the_event_of_serious_faults_do_not_drive_the_vehicle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtDefects"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddComBox"
           android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
           android:text="@string/defects"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

           <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtDefectsBox"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cboxScrew"
             android:layout_below="@+id/txtDefects"
             android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

           <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnHome"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cboxOil"
             android:text="@string/home" />

      </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

and this is that java class for that page (**Checklist**)

```
   package com.example.ifmdb;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

      public class Checklist extends Activity {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.checklist);

          Button btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
          btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                  finish();
            }

        });
    }

     }
```

I have an error with a line of code

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

This is the error---

```
The constructor Intent(Context, void) is undefined
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Variable Initializer
```

Comment: I guess you missed something, this line is incomplete - Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),   ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private Activity mActivity = null;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      mActivity = this;
      Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
      btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),Checklist.class);
                    mActivity.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
     }
           });    
           }

          }
```

Comment: it still doesnt like this line                                      new Intent(mActivity.getApplicationContext(),Checklist.this);

Comment: multiple markers at this line                                                         -No enclosing instance of the type checklist is accessible in scope.   -The consturctor Instent (Contex, Checklist) is undefined

Comment: @user3432846 chenge to Checklist.class

Comment: yes i had it added was missing part of the code, thanks everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

In the code its missing the syntax.

[here is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

You can try this way. Hope it helps.

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),Checklist.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
     }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed, you were right Atul O Holic i was missing a part of the code.

heres the working solution

```
package com.example.ifmdb;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Checklist.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
         }
    });    
    }

   }
```